# Understanding javascript Objects

Tags: javascript

I have what is I believe an extremely basic javascript question that for some silly reason I am struggling with.

If you visualise the object below.  How would I call one function from inside the 'init' function?

```
TC.design = {

        init : function(){
            //How would I run the loadPage function here? 
        },
        loadPage : function(){

        }
}
```

I have tried this.loadPage(); which I expected to work but it returns undefined.

I am clearly not grasping something fundamental here, hopefully someone can explain.

**EDIT:**  This is now solved...

Thanks to **Joseph Silber** and **Rocket** I have realised my error...

The problem arose due to a misunderstanding of the javascript .call() function.  I was calling `init` with `TC.design.init.call()` which I now understand is incorrect.  My apologies....

Comment: How are you calling `init`?  You might be changing the value of `this` when you do.

Comment: `this.loadPage()` should work: http://jsfiddle.net/85AWT/

Comment: Of course `this.loadPage()` works. You get `undefined` because you returned `undefined` (which may mean that you didn't use `return` keyword in `loadPage`, like in the code you've shown us). Note that you `undefined` is actually what you **get**. This means that `loadPage` fired. Your code would raise an exception otherwise.

Comment: @Joseph your quick fiddle provided the answer which was unbelievably simple.  I was calling init incorectly due to a misunderstanding of the use of the javascript .call() function.  I was using TC.design.call() instead of TC.design.init();  If you wan't to put your fiddle into an answer I will accept as it was your fiddle that gave me the solution.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your `init` function, `this` refers to the `TG.design` object; `this.loadPage()` should work, but you have to call the `init` function properly in order to invoke it.

Here's some sample code:

```
var TC = {
    design: {
        init: function() {
            this.loadPage();
        },
        loadPage: function() {
            conosle.log('Works');
        }
    }
};

TC.design.init();​
```

and here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/85AWT/

Answer (score 2):

Wont this work?

```
TC.design = {
        init : function(){
            TC.design.loadPage();
        },
        loadPage : function(){
           alert('Booga')
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes the above works fine... however I was trying to understand why this.loadPage wouldn't work.... I have now found the reason.  I was calling init as TC.design.init.call();  doh!

Answer (score 2):

`this.loadPage` should work fine, unless you change the value of `this`.

For example:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    TC.design.init();
}, 1000);
```

This will work fine.  When `init` is called, `this` is `TC.design`.

```
setTimeout(TC.design.init, 1000);
```

This won't work.  Now, `this` will be `window` inside of `init`.  Therefore, `this.loadPage` won't work.

So, be careful how you call `TC.design.init`.

Comment: In this case the code would raise an exception (trying to call undefined `this.loadPage`), but OP states that it returns `undefined`.

Comment: @freakish: True.  I'll leave this here anyway.  Just as an FYI.